# How can I return scraped information from my scrapy spider to my Flask server?

Tags: flask, scrapy

I want to call my scraper from my flask server and have the value returned to the server. At the moment I am using subprocess to call the scraper, and a POST request to send the scraped information.

`subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'mySpiderClass'])`

can I use a variable equal to crawlerprocess to return the values instead?